# How do I format this without the ends cutting off printf

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

Basically I'm doing this school project with the 100 lockers problem and I need to use `printf()`. All my simulations are set. The problem is getting the code to print out as a 10x10 grid.
I have no clue why it won't format to a 10x10 and when I move the console the ends get cut off.

```java
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //VARIABLES

        boolean allLockers[] = new boolean[100]; // create 100 lockers

        int[] numLockers = new int[100]; //numbering system

        int person = 0; //declaring people

        boolean[][] grid = new boolean[10][10]; //2D grid


        //SIMULATION

        for (person = 1; person <= 100; person++) // for every person
        {
            for (int locker = 1; locker <= 100; locker++) //for every locker
            {
                if (locker % person == 0) //using modulus to check if its a multiple
                {
                    allLockers[locker - 1] = !allLockers[locker - 1]; //sets locker to false
                }
            }
        }

        //GRID
        int increase = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                grid[i][j] = allLockers[increase];
                System.out.printf("%1b ", grid[i][j]);
                increase++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: After `for(int j=0;j<10;j++){` - print a new line?

Comment: I did   System.out.printf("%n");    ,that did not make it print out as a grid

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have output as something like that,

> true  false   false   true    false   false   false   false   true    false
> false false   false   false   false   true    false   false   false   false
> false false   false   false   true    false   false   false   false   false
> false false   false   false   false   true    false   false   false   false
> false false   false   false   false   false   false   false   true    false
> false false   false   false   false   false   false   false   false   false
> false false   false   true    false   false   false   false   false   false
> false false   false   false   false   false   false   false   false   false
> true  false   false   false   false   false   false   false   false   false
> false false   false   false   false   false   false   false   false   true

and also if you have to use printf, you can use grid code at the below,

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                grid[i][j] = allLockers[increase];
                System.out.printf("%1b\t", grid[i][j]);
                increase++;
            }
            System.out.printf("%n");
        }
```

As @Abra suggested in the comments, I edited \n with %n.